# Two almost identical constructors

Tags: c#

In my application I have a class which I use with an object initializer. But I think that it's better to specify a constructor for the class. So I made the following code:

My class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to specify a constructor. But the Url property should be optional. I don't know how to do this. Because when I specify two different constructors one with the url and one without it, it feels like duplicated code.

```
public Person(string name, string secondName, string address, int age, DateTime birthDate, string url)
{
    Name = name;
    SecondName = secondName;
    Address = address;
    Age = age;
    BirthDate = birthDate;
    Url = url; // This is optional
}
```

Is it bad to specify two constructors that are almost the same or is that the best solution. Or should I just use the object initializer

Edit:
To clarify my question a bit. I'm now creating an object from this class as followed.

```
Person person = new Person(name, secondName, address, age, birthDate)
if(hasUrl)
{
    person.Url = "theUrlHere"
}
```

Comment: You should just use object initializers, unless you want your class to be immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the URL is the last parameter, you can make it optional (since C# 4.0). Just assign it the desired default value in the parameter list.

```
public Person(
    string name, string secondName, string address, int age, DateTime birthDate,
    string url = null)
{ ... }
```

Now you can omit the URL when calling the constructor.

```
var p1 = new Person("John", "Smith", "New York", 17, new DateTime(2001, 3, 12));
var p2 = new Person("Sue", "Miller", "York", 22, new DateTime(1995, 7, 5), "www.sue-mi.com");
```

See: [Named and Optional Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments)

Comment: I edited my question a little bit. Should I provide the complete call of the constructor in my if? Or is what I have now just fine?

Comment: You could just include the mandatory parameters in the constructor and pass the optional ones in an object initializer or assign them later directly. Btw. You can calculate the age from the birth date. I would just make the age a getter only property with the age calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You could create two constructors and call the first one from the second:

```
public Person(string name, string secondName, string address, int age, DateTime birthDate)
{
    Name = name;
    SecondName = secondName;
    Address = address;
    Age = age;
    BirthDate = birthDate;
}

public Person(string name, string secondName, string address, int age, DateTime birthDate, string url)
    : this (name, secondName, address, age, birthDate)
{
    Url = url;
}
```

Or you could make the `url` parameter optional:

```
public Person(string name, string secondName, string address, int age, DateTime birthDate, string url = null)
{
    Name = name;
    SecondName = secondName;
    Address = address;
    Age = age;
    BirthDate = birthDate;
    Url = url;
}
```

Comment: I'd normally recommend invoking the "canonical" constructor from the "shorter" one, rather than the other way round. That tends to make it easier to reason about how everything is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

- Just provide a parameterless constructor, and use object initializers to populate the properties
- Provide two constructor signatures, almost certainly delegating from "the one without the URL" to "the one with the URL". For example:

  ```
  public Person(string name, string secondName, string address,
                int age, DateTime birthDate)
      : this(name, secondName, address, age, birthDate, null)
  {
  }

  public Person(string name, string secondName, string address,
                int age, DateTime birthDate, string url)
  {
      // Set all the properties here
  }
  ```
- Provide a single constructor and use an optional parameter for the URL, e.g.

  ```
  public Person(string name, string secondName, string address,
                int age, DateTime birthDate, string url = null)
  ```

Note the `= null` part for the `url` parameter, which makes it an *optional parameter*. If the calling code doesn't provide a value, the compiler will pass `null` (the default value as specified here) implicitly.

In the cases where you provide these "long" constructor signatures, you may *also* want to provide a parameterless one for users who would prefer to use object initializers.

Comment: Is it better to use a constructor if you want to force a user to provide the right information? Because with an object initializer an user can leave out essential information. If I understand it correct

Comment: The question is, who you mean by user? If it's someone entering data in a form, then you can't force them to enter data this way. Instead you would have to provide a validation mechanism in your form. If the "user" is another developer using your code, the constructor can help.

Comment: Yes, I meant another developer.

Comment: @Littleprogrammingwizard: Yes, that can be useful - but at that point I wouldn't have writable automatically implemented properties that don't provide any validation. I'd often suggest using *read-only* properties in this situation: validate everything in the constructor, assign the properties values, and then callers will know that any instance is valid and immutable.